# Understanding function call priority between regular and generic versions

Tags: swift, function, generics

In this code:

```
class Foo {
}

func go(input: Foo) {
    print("Non-generic called")
}

func go<T>(input: T) {
    print("Generic called")
}

var foo:Foo = Foo()
go(foo) // Non-generic called
```

I'm just curious why the non-generic version gets called instead of the generic one? Does the compiler just prioritize specific types over generics?

Comment: For a great explanation of how Swift decides which function to call, see [this post from Airspeed Velocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/09/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler prioritizes the most constrained function. So a function that matches with a `where` clause that requires a subtype will beat one that matches with a `where` clause that requires a supertype. A function that matches with a `where` clause will beat one that doesn't. A function that explicitly calls out its types will beat one that matches only on a generic. The specific rules are pretty complicated (and in some cases seem to be [a little ad hoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856645/type-inference-fails-when-using-nil-coalescing-operator-with-two-optionals) when things are on the edge), but overall that's the intent.

You can think of the above as:

```
// Any T
func go<T>(input: T) {
    print("Generic called")
}

// A very constrained T, so clearly you wanted to override.
func go<T where T == Foo>(input: T) {
    print("Non-generic called")
}
```

Comment: the second one leads to error: same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'T' non-generic. try func go<T where T:Foo>(input: T) {
    print("Non-generic called")
} instead.

Comment: Correct; the second is not legal syntax, but it represents what `go(input: Foo)` means.